# Remove event listener with additional arguments

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am trying to remove an event listener that takes additional arguments, but no luck so far. My event listener has the following structure:

```
const testHandler = (strToLog) => {
  return(e) => {
    if (e.key === "a") console.log(strToLog)
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", testHandler("Hello world!"));
```

And now I can't get rid of it, because  `document.removeEventListener("keydown", testHandler);` doesn't work.

I suppose it has something to do with the `return(e)` arrow function inside of `testHandler()`, but I'm a JavaScript rookie and the event handler itself is already stack-overflowed.

Is there a way to remove this event handler as it is? If not, how do I have to modify the handler so I can remove it? Sorry if I overlooked an existing post about this topic; none of the posts I found seemed to cover my scenario with the `return(e)` arrow function.

Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Comment: You need to pass the same function back in. Save `testHandler("Hello world!")` in a variable and pass that variable to `removeEventListener`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was lightning fast! If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it's not removing because the remove method is not able to find the `testHandler` method since it's different from the declaration.

You might find this reading interesting about [Matching event listeners for removal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#matching_event_listeners_for_removal)

For your case you just need to remove the same function that you've added:

`document.removeEventListener("keydown", testHandler("Hello world!"));`

or as evolutionxbox post on comments, add this function to a variable, and pass it as the parameteres both for `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

```
const parameter = testHandler("Hello world!");

document.addEventListener("keydown", parameter);
document.removeEventListener("keydown", parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `testHandler` a little bit that it saves a reference of the handler. So you can remove the registered handler later by calling it with the same parameter.

Here's a example that using this technique:

```js
const testHandler = (strToLog) => {
    if(!testHandler._map) {
        testHandler._map = {};
    }

    if(!testHandler._map[strToLog]) {
        testHandler._map[strToLog] = (e) => {
            if (e.key === "a") console.log(strToLog)
        }
    }

    return testHandler._map[strToLog];
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", testHandler("Hello world!"));

// this removes the same event listener above
document.removeEventListener("keydown", testHandler("Hello world!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I too am a java script noob! But I do think I may have come up with a solution to your problem. For me when I try to add an event listener, using the function name as the second argument. and then calling it in the remove listener function works!

Here is an example based on my code I hope it helps.

```
   window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
   window.removeEventListener('resize', resize());
    
  const resize = () => {
    if (mobile === undefined) return
    if (window.innerWidth < 600) setIsMobile(true)
    if (window.innerWidth > 600) setIsMobile(false)
  }
```